# Doubts on definition of the Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, lie-derivative

I have some difficulties to see why the definition of the lie derivative makes sense.

I'm going to use the notations of Lee's book.

Let $M$ manifold and $W$ a smooth vector field on $M$. Let $\eta$ the flow of another smooth vector field $V$

$$(L_VW)_p=d/dt(d(\eta_{-t})_{\eta_t(p)}(W_{\eta_t(p)})=\lim_t (d(\eta_{-t})_{\eta_t(p)}(W_{\eta_t(p)})-W_p)/t $$

where the derivative and the limit are computed in $0$

Now:

1) Is the second equality a definition ?

2) I don't understand what a derivative or a limit of these objects means. I would like to find a function $F$ depending on $t$ such that $(L_VW)_p=d/dt F(t)$ computed in $0$. My problem is that if I take $F(t)=d(\eta_{-t})_{\eta_t(p)}(W_{\eta_t(p)})$ I have a function with values not in $\mathbb R $ (I think they are in $T_pM$, right?) So how can I derive a such $F:\mathbb R\to T_pM$ ?

Is this problem just that I do not know what a derivative in a topological vector space is or something like this?

Same problem with the Lie derivative of a tensor field.

P.S. Moreover, the symbol $d/dt$ in the definition of the Lie derivative should be interpreted as the velocity of a curve or as the limit of the difference quotient? Or, more in general, the velocity of a curve into $T_pM$ is actually equals to the limit of the different quotient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not as bad as you fear:  $F(t)=d(\eta_{-t})_{\eta_t(p)}(W_{\eta_t(p)})$ takes, for any value of $t$, value in $T_p M$. You surely can take the difference of two vectors, $F(t)$ and $F(0)$,  which belong to the same vector space. Similarly you can divide by a constant ($t$) and take limits. If you don't like thinking of limits in $T_p M$ just remember that $T_p M \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$ for $n=$dim$(M)$. You probably have seen derivatives and limits of function valued in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is just that. To answer (1), the second equality is not a definition, but follows from the definition of derivative by what I said before.

Comment: When you say "take limits" you mean taking limits in $T_pM$ with respect to its topology given as smooth manifold right?

Comment: After this remark I will accept your answer. The point is that I saw that many times functions from a subset of $\mathbb R$ to $T_pM$ occur in diff geometry and many times we are interested in their derivatives $d/dt$ but I want to be sure that this refers to the topological structure of the tangent space. As you noticed, also the structure of vector space is fundamental in order to consider the difference quotient

Comment: I was wondering: the symbol of $d/dt$ in the definition of the lie derivative must be interpreted like a velocity of a curve or like the limit of a difference quotient?

Comment: How to formulate an answer depends a bit on which definition of $T_p M$ and $TM$ you start with. Anyway, to be honest I have never explicitly checked that the topology induced on $T_p M$ as a (topological) subspace of $TM$ is the same as that of $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, it must be so for at least  two reasons: for finite dimensional vector spaces there is a unique topology making them into a topological vector space; for each $p$ you actually have a homeomorphism $T_p M\simeq \mathbb{R}^n$. SO really, you can think of it as having the usual $\mathbb{R}^n$ topology.

Comment: For your second question, I am pretty sure both ways of interpreting $d/dt$ will lead you to the same answer: $F$ is a curve on $T_p M$ so $(L_V W)_p=  F_* (d/dt |_0) = F ^\prime (0)$.